# Django is not imported

Tags: python, django, server, web-deployment

I cant understand why is this thing working like that. It can do runserver, but cant do collectstatic, how can i fix it?(I am deploying it)
[image]

Comment: For future reference, you should post error messages directly as text, instead of a screenshot. For one thing, they can often be longer than you can capture in a single screen. Also, I find text easier to edit when I need to redact sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i have just typed python3 instead python, and it worked. It's strange that you need to specify a three in venv

Comment: What OS are you on? If you are on linux, what does `which python` and `which python3` output?